# What is "sym.definition" in Uglify3?

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs

I'm trying to uglify a javascript function by UglifyJS3, specifically @ https://skalman.github.io/UglifyJS-online/.  But I'm getting an error

> TypeError: sym.definition is not a function

that I unable to resolve.

To decipher the error message, I've stripped and manipulated the code down to a bare minimum, trivial code that still produces the error.

```
function f() {

    const a      = Math.abs(2);
    const [b,c]  = [2, 3];

}
```

Despite the obvious trivialness, the uglifier ( with default options) gives me the aforementioned error.   The following, on the other hand, resolves the issue:  simply removing **either** of the lines in `f()`, lead with the `const [b,c]...` expression; OR do not use the destructing assignment.

The easiest and only available fix (for my code) is simply to stop using the destructing, nevertheless, I need to know why this is happening.  What exactly is the meaning of the error `TypeError: sym.definition is not a function`?

I can't see how this simple code is producing an error, so is it the settings?   Is this a bug in `uglify-es 3.3.9`?  or specific to `https://skalman.github.io/UglifyJS-online/`?

Any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:**  @SparkFountain  has pointed me to right direction.  While the discussion in the cited link refers to problem in v3.3.10 and the NOT v3.3.9 that I cite, this is because the online uglifier incorrectly cites v3.3.9 as the source.  In fact, it is running v3.3.10.  While I still do not know the cause of the error, I'm satisfied that this simply a BUG, limited only to https://skalman.github.io/UglifyJS-online/ (as of Aug2019) and requires effort, on my part, to move away from that site.  Thanks @SparkFoutain.

Comment: Have a look at this discussion on GitHub: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/2896

Comment: it doesn't support ES6 out of the box:  `uglify-js only supports JavaScript (ECMAScript 5).
To minify ECMAScript 2015 or above, transpile using tools like Babel.`  https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js

Comment: You should post your update as an answer which you could then accept